I can not run my tests on playwright with webkit
In other browsers i still can run my test cases, but there is issue with the webkit.
Error: browserType.launch: Target page, context or browser has been closed
Browser logs:
 /home/anush_av/.cache/ms-playwright/webkit-1983/pw_run.sh --inspector-pipe --no-startup-window
 pid=195578
[pid=195578][err] /home/anush_av/.cache/ms-playwright/webkit-1983/minibrowser-gtk/bin/MiniBrowser: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
Call log:

 /home/anush_av/.cache/ms-playwright/webkit-1983/pw_run.sh --inspector-pipe --no-startup-window
 pid=195578
[pid=195578][err] /home/anush_av/.cache/ms-playwright/webkit-1983/minibrowser-gtk/bin/MiniBrowser: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

I tried upgrade webkit and playwright

Please share a [mcve], relevant system details, and a Playwright version. Thanks. Did you see #27615, for example?

With other browsers works correct, only webkit have issues. I use Ubuntu 22.04. Already did:
npm i -D @playwright/test@next.
npm exec playwright install --force --with-deps chromium firefox webkit chrome msedge.
apt upgrade.
But it also doesn't solve my problem.
Playwright version: 1.40.0

I did: sudo snap remove code.
Now there is another issue: Error: page.goto: TLS support is not available
